# Pass any subclass of Object as a parameter

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass

I'm wondering how to pass any subclass into a method. I have a board of tiles. Tiles can contain characters, but all characters are sublclasses of Character. I want to set a Tile to contain a character as it's occupant. This is what i would like to implement:

```
VikingRecruit oden = new VikingRecruit();       
this.gameboard.PlaceItem(0, 0, oden);
```

VikingRecruit is a subclass of Character. I would like any type of Character to be able to be passed.

Comment: You should read on polymorphism.

Comment: Then make the parameter type `Character`, although that's a poor choice of class name since `java.lang.Character` exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What @dguay suggested. I would start by reading up on a tutorial about polymorphism in java, maybe [this one](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_polymorphism.htm). As also mentioned - I would rename Character to something like CharacterPiece or CharacterType, as Character is already defined in java.

Then your placeItem (first letter should be lower case) method signature would look something like:

```
public void placeItem(int a, int b, CharacterPiece piece) { ... }
```

And VikingRecruit should implement the CharacterPiece interface (or extend if you're using abstraction).

```
public class VikingRecruit implements CharacterPiece { ... }
```

That would make what you listed above work.